# Vertical Dot Navigation with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am working on a dot navigation for sections in a one page layout. It currently will go to the sections on click. I also have been able to get the labels and dot change to show on hover. But I am struggling to have the navigation reflect the section when scrolling. I have added bootstrap to jsfiddle external resources and added the recommended body code, but something is still apparently missing. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/carincamen/ram0Ly92/27/

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".Vnav">

$(document).ready(function($){
        $('a').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
        });

            $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
            $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
        }); 

       $('.vNav a').hover(function() {
           $(this).find('.label').show();
           }, function() {
           $(this).find('.label').hide();
       });

});
```

Comment: i'm not sure what bootstrap provides out of the box, but if it doesn't do this for you, you need to bind to the scroll event and track for changes to top. take a look at this: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Have you consider using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for it?
You can use [the vertical navigation option](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html#secondPage) combined with the [autoScrolling:false](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html).
This will do it if you work with full screen pages. Otherwise it might not be the best solution.

Comment: Making progress. Just needing the final touches to have the dots fill in as the page scrolls.

 http://jsfiddle.net/carincamen/ram0Ly92/

Answer (score 0):

With lots of research, I was able to get all the functions working properly. The final key was using parPosition. Here is the final code.

http://jsfiddle.net/carincamen/ram0Ly92/

```
$(document).ready(function($){
      var parPosition = [];
    $('.par').each(function() {
        parPosition.push($(this).offset().top);
    });

    $('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

        $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
    }); 

   $('.vNav a').hover(function() {
       $(this).find('.label').show();
       }, function() {
       $(this).find('.label').hide();
   });

       $(document).scroll(function(){
    var position = $(document).scrollTop(),
            index; 
            for (var i=0; i<parPosition.length; i++) {
            if (position <= parPosition[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
  $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
        $('.vNav ul li a:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
    });

        $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
    });   
});
```